# XSLT adding in space on capital letters?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I found a similar question asking about how to split XSLT on capital letters, but I didn't understand fully how to use it. I apologize for my incompentence here, but could someone please give me an explantation on how one could split:

```
 <field name="HelloWorld">this doesn't matter </field>
```

So the gist would be take the name attribute and split it to be:

```
 <p>Hello World: This doesn't matter</p>
```

I have it all but the breaking it up part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming XSLT/XPath 2.0 you can use `replace('HelloWorld', '\p{Lu}', ' $0')` to get `Hello World` so you can use `replace(@name, '\p{Lu}', ' $0')`.